# How do I register for keyup event using NG2 reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In NG2, declaratively: 
you can use (***keyup.enter***) for registering "press-enter" events. Like this:

```
<input type="text" #txtEnteredMessage (keyup.enter)="sendMessage(txtEnteredMessage.value);">
```

In NG2, **reactive forms**: 
I can use the *valueChanges* observable to listen for changes. But this is not triggered when pressing enter.

How do I register for keyup.enter events using reactive forms (=formcontrol)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution that uses Subject:

```
//inside your hml file 
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="txtMessageEnter$.next();">

//inside your .ts file
constructor() {       
   this.txtMessageEnter$ = new ReplaySubject<any>();
}
...
this.txtMessageEnter$.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: `import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs/Rx";`